# What are the three arguments to Gdk.threads_add_idle()?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject, gdk

Using python and the `gi.repository` module, I am trying to call `Gdk.threads_add_idle`, but I get the error message that three arguments are required. The [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/2.22/gdk-Threads.html#gdk-threads-add-idle), however, only mentions two args.

You can try the function (on a linux only, i guess) by typing the following in a python interpreter:

```
from gi.repository import Gdk

Gdk.threads_add_idle(...)
```

Any ideas what the three args are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking on a source code search engine, I was able to find a python project using [that call](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=iaOddY7MjZkG_AZM-XSzCrWAmC8&cid=Z2GcLmDDO0A&s=threads_add_idle&pp=0&fl=Python&ff=1&filterChecked=true&mp=1&ml=0&me=1&md=1&browser=Default#L313).

```
Gdk.threads_add_idle(GLib.PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE, self._idle_call, data)
```

It looks like introspection data is wrong, the priority should already default to `PRIORITY_DEFAULT_IDLE` (as specified in the the documentation you pointed out). You should file a bug on http://bugzilla.gnome.org.

**UPDATE:**

Pouria's bug report has been resolved `NOTABUG`, as this is a [naming confusion between the C and Python API](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692280#c1).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try in my project, when I have the time, and will file a bug as well if necessary.

Comment: This works, thanks again. I also filed a [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=692280).